# AsyncTask.onPostExecute() is not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I write some code to read RSS news from Google news, and update `ProgressBar`. My RSS Reader works correctly, and update is done, but `onPostExecute()` isn't called, can anyone explain why ?

```
public class loadNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        ArrayList<News> news = new ArrayList<News>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<News>> allData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<News>>();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // links to get news
            String[] types = { "World", "Bussiness", "Science and Technology",
                    "Entertainment", "Sport", "Health" };
            String[] links = {
                    // World
                    "https://news.google.com.eg/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=ar_me&hl=ar&topic=w&output=rss",
                    // Business
                    "https://news.google.com.eg/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=ar_me&hl=ar&topic=b&output=rss",
                    // science and technology
                    "https://news.google.com.eg/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=ar_me&hl=ar&topic=t&output=rss",
                    // Entertainment
                    "https://news.google.com.eg/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=ar_me&hl=ar&topic=e&output=rss",
                    // Sport
                    "https://news.google.com.eg/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=ar_me&hl=ar&topic=s&output=rss",
                    // Health
                    "https://news.google.com.eg/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=ar_me&hl=ar&topic=m&output=rss" };
            URL url = null;

            for (int j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {

                try {
                    url = new URL(links[j]);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                DocumentBuilder builder = null;
                try {
                    builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                            .newDocumentBuilder();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodes.item(i);
                    Element element = (Element) node;
                    NodeList Ti = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    Element el = (Element) Ti.item(0);
                    NodeList temp = el.getChildNodes();
                    String Title = temp.item(0).getNodeValue();
                    Ti = element.getElementsByTagName("link");
                    el = (Element) Ti.item(0);
                    temp = el.getChildNodes();
                    String Link = temp.item(0).getNodeValue();
                    // setting news into arraylist
                    News _news = new News();
                    _news.title = Title;
                    Log.i("this is title of news" + i, _news.title);
                    _news.link = Link;
                    news.add(_news);
                }
                allData.add(news);
                news.clear();
                publishProgress(16);
            }
            publishProgress(4);
            Log.i("end of do in background", "ending");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

            pb.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExcute(String result) {

            Log.i("we in postexcute", "onpostexcute");
            tv.setText("done");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your code and in your post execute there is no use of String result and there you just want to set text in some textview, so if not required then change your code as follow and try

```
public class LoadNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

//your variables and other methods..,.

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //your code
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void s)
{
     //your code
     System.out.println("Just for test, remove it");
}
```